# Precisamos mesmo da tag "script"?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica, wikis-de-tags

Não sei quando foi criada, não sei se já foi removida alguma vez, em uma breve leitura sobre as perguntas que a usam não vi utilidade real alguma para ela:

- [Perguntas com a tag [script]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script)

As informações e *Wiki da tag* também não ajudam

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/script/info

A fonte citada é uma explicação bastante breve sobre o que é script e sobre *shells* que realmente e não demonstra utilidade alguma para o wiki e "o wiki de tag", fora que no wiki dela não tem uma orientação de uso a TAG.

Gostaria de saber a opinião da comunidade sobre o que fazer com ela. Devemos remove-la?

> *Nota:* Como disse, não sei se ela já foi "removida antes e voltou".

Comment: Me corrijam se eu estiver errado, mas o script normalmente é [o antagônico de programa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2286552/7690982), que não possui tag. Então creio que esta tag não faz sentido mesmo, pois ambos possuem programação em alguma linguagem e é mais correto criar a tag da linguagem utilizada. E dando uma olhada na tag, me parece que a maioria das perguntas são de baixa qualidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como dani disse,maiorias são pergunta de baixa qualidade,melhor nós alerta ao usuário ou dado downvote,que não é útil usar a tag script. Eu não vejo problema usa-la,mas é inútil e desnecessário.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper ótimo, então **agora você entende a utilidade do META**, você expôs sua opinião sobre a TAG, e é isso mesmo o que fazemos, discutimos se ela é útil, inútil, indiferente, ou tem situações que pode ser um ou outro, assim como todas tags que já foram debatidas e muitas hoje nem existem mais: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags - Bem vindo ao META do SOpt, contamos com seu apoio.

Answer (score 9):

Acredito que sim, é necessário removê-la.

Se analisarmos as perguntas, podemos notar que a tag `script` é bem genérica, e junto com ela, as pessoas que usam colocam vários tipos diferentes de tags e linguagens de programação, sendo que a palavra `script` sozinho não se refere à nenhuma.

Ao meu ver, manter essa tag no SOpt só vai causar confusão nas pessoas que estiverem procurando pela mesma